# Kolmogorov-Smirnov with parameter estimates

Tags: estimation, sample, kolmogorov-smirnov-test

Can someone explain in as clear a (formalish mathematical) way as possible why the KS test in original form with parameter estimates is unreliable?

Comment: It's not "unreliable": it's *wrong*. Specifically, it calculates the p-value assuming the parameters are known; when they are estimated, the p-value as calculated under such a contrafactual assumption has almost no meaning.

Answer (score 4):

When fitting parameters, the distribution of the values of the test statistic tend to be much smaller than with a fully specified distribution (because fitted distributions match the data better than the corresponding population distributions, since you optimize for fit).

This leads to smaller significance levels which lowers the power curve. Your p-values correspondingly don't carry the meaning that they should (the conditional probability statements associated with the p-values don't apply).

There are modifications of the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test (search the site on *Lilliefors*) which solve that problem, but the test is no longer distribution-free. You need a new table for testing each distribution. (Lilliefors did tables for normal and exponential cases with parameter estimation.)